# Reorder Array based on X value's count and alphabet

Tags: php, arrays

For example i have a string like that.

```
d,b,a,a,b,a,c
```

There is 3 'a', 2 'b', 1 'd' , 1 'c'

Then i explode it:

```
[0] => d
[1] => b
[2] => a
[3] => a
[4] => b
[5] => a
[6] => c
```

array_unique(array) gives me this:

```
[0] => d
[1] => b
[2] => a
[3] => c
```

What i need:

```
[0] => a
[1] => b
[2] => c
[3] => d

0 => a because there was 3 a in array.
1 => b because there was 2 b in array.
2 => c because there was 1 c in array. c is equal to d but it comes earlier in alphabet.
3 => d because there was 1 c in array.
```

Sorry for broken english.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but start by looking at PHP's `array_count_values()` function. That will help you count up the number of times each value occurs, and then you can do some sorting with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a solution along these lines...

```
<?php
    $sampleString = "d,b,b,a,a,b,a,b,c";
    $sampleArray = explode(",",$sampleString);
    $arrayCounts = array_count_values($sampleArray);
    arsort($arrayCounts);
    $finalArray = array_keys($arrayCounts);
    print_r($finalArray);
?>
```